# Minimum integer in array of integers C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create a program to find the minimum integer in an array of integers. This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int findMinimum(int array);

int findMinimum(int array){
  int arraySize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
  int minimum = array[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    if (arraySize[i] < minimum){
      minimum = arraySize[i];
    }
  }
  return minimum;
}

int main(){
  int array[7] = {17,2,10,291,28,10,11};
  int minimum = findMinimum(array);
  cout << "The minimum of the array is: " << minimum;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
    /Users/Danny/Desktop/C++/Practice/arrays.cpp:9:22: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
  int minimum = array[0];
                ~~~~~^~
/Users/Danny/Desktop/C++/Practice/arrays.cpp:11:18: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
    if (arraySize[i] < minimum){
        ~~~~~~~~~^~
/Users/Danny/Desktop/C++/Practice/arrays.cpp:12:26: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
      minimum = arraySize[i];
                ~~~~~~~~~^~
/Users/Danny/Desktop/C++/Practice/arrays.cpp:20:17: error: no matching function for call to 'findMinimum'
  int minimum = findMinimum(array);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/Danny/Desktop/C++/Practice/arrays.cpp:7:5: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int [7]' to 'int' for 1st argument
int findMinimum(int array){
```

How do I fix these errors? Thank you.

Comment: Well, `array` in `findMinimum()`, despite the name, isn't an array... it's just an `int`.

Comment: @Barry but when I create an integer array, its "int arrayName[2] = {1,2};". What type do I call for then?

Comment: The `[2]` part is part of the type as well - `arrayName` isn't an `int`, it's an `int[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

The function head should be:

```
int findMinimum(int* array)
```

However, for an `int*`, this won't work:

```
int arraySize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
```

Therefore you should also pass the size to the function:

```
int findMinimum(int* array, int size)
```

You should also consider to use std::vector instead of the array.

Comment: He could also simply pass int array[7] to findMinimum, in case he doesn't want to bother with pointers.

Comment: Almost what I was about to write, nice! One note I'd like to add is that while passing a pointer and the size is quite natural, keeping to how the STL does things would mean passing a pointer to the begin and one past the end of the array. Oh, and the pointer should probably have type `int const *`.

Comment: @Fang Though the sizeof approach won't work with that, too.

Answer (score 2):

This may be cheating:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    int array[7] = { 17, 2, 10, 291, 28, 10, 11 };
    int min = *std::min_element(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
    std::cout << "The minimum of the array is: " << min << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Need a `*` there for `std::min_element`'s return value.

Answer (score 1):

What you passed in this line

`int minimum = findMinimum(array);`

is actually a pointer to an `int` array... actually, the pointer to the first element. So, you want to change your function signature to

`int findMinimum(int* array)`

---

In the modified function `int findMinimum(int* array)`, the line below will be wrong

```
int arraySize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
```

because, `array` is already a decomposed pointer here... so you want to change the function again to

`int findMinimum(int* array, int size)`

Your complete program will be:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int findMinimum(int* array, int arraySize);

int findMinimum(int* array, int arraySize){
  int minimum = array[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    if (arraySize[i] < minimum){
      minimum = arraySize[i];
    }
  }
  return minimum;
}

int main(){
  int array[7] = {17,2,10,291,28,10,11};
  int minimum = findMinimum(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));
  cout << "The minimum of the array is: " << minimum;
}
```